# Use of array in like query with multiple append search filter

Tags: laravel

When I select more than 1 `Root Scheme` then it show only one result but I want to get 2 or more results in `Query Append`

```
 if($rootschemeid != ""){
    $query->where('rootschemes.rootschemeid','like','%'.$rootschemeid.'%');
 }
```

Actually, I use `Query Append` in Search Functionality in laravel using Ajax Request but I can't get Proper result. I have more then 1 root schemes. If I select 1 by 1 then it gives me proper result but if select both at a time then it shows only first one. I also tried using `impload`, `wherein`,`orwhere`,`subquery`,`like` operators but did not get proper result.

Comment: Can you show us the full implementation of this query? I suspect you are appending `where` statements. This would mean you are refining your constraints. If you would use `orWhere`(in the right context) you should resolve this.

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducaple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I create First main query with leftjoin of rootscheme member and on search check empty condition after i used Append query in main query  and get result 1,2 (this is rootschemeid) and try to get Result And For Getting Result I Used Where first time After orWhere or Impoled and Like Query. Please Give Me Any Solution if You Have some different solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
I found Answer Of My Query That I use Query like This,

$query->whereIn('rootschemes.rootschemeid',$rootschemeid); 

And If Any query Append After Query I Should use orWhere with subquery of laravel ,
suppose After Rootscheme Query we need to Append any other query like scheme query then I would write a query like ...

$query->orwhere(function($q) use ($schemeid){
 $q->whereIn('schemes.schemeid',$schemeid);
});
```